# Conditional Attributes c#

Tags: c#, attributes, conditional-statements

In my program, I have two attributes: `VisibleToA` and `VisibleToB`. These are used to restrict visibility of certain functions through the API.

The problem occurs when I need to have a function visible to `A` or `B`. Attributes are "anded" together by default such that I create a method:

```
[VisibleToA(), VisibleToB()]
public void ConditionallyVisibleMethod() { }
```

It is effectively equivalent to `VisibleToAandB`. This is a problem because if they are both true, then it makes it impossible for `A` to see it, since `A` is not `B`, and makes it impossible for `B` to see it, since `B` is not `A`.

Because of this, I want to make it visible to `A` OR `B`, only needing to satisfy a single condition in order to view it.

So, simple fix, I created an `OrConditionAttribute` that takes in an array of `Attributes`. Loop through the condition on each one, if true, return true. Then I found out attributes can only have parameters of primitive types due to how they are written in the metadata.

They have to be attributes, due to how the structure of the program works, so I need to use one in one way or another. I thought about passing in `strings` representing the attributes' class names, then inside the `OrConditionAttribute` create an instance of the class from the `string` name, but I wasn't sure how to pass in parameters as well since `VisibleToA` and `VisibleToB` both require parameters.

Is there a way to implement this functionality?

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to answer because there are some important details about your restrictions which are left unexplained, in particular, what you mean by "due to how the structure of the program works". Are you using attribute classes somebody else has written? Or are you designing your own system? This would be helpful in finding an answer.

Comment: If these are your attributes then surely it's up to you how they are processed so if you want them ORed then that's how you should process them. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: My program is using an API which relies on attributes. Every class and function (even some parameters) use them and I must tag my code with said attributes so that they can communicate with the API. I agree it's a little weird but also makes sense once you get used to it.

Comment: Is this API publicly available? It might be helpful to link to it so we can find an answer for you.

Comment: Yes, this is the attribute I attempted to extend to make the `OrCondition` https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/api/Discord.Commands.PreconditionAttribute.html My two attributes are of different groups.

Comment: I see. Can you update your question to explain exactly what you're trying to achieve with the API? I or somebody else may be able to offer further assistance. From what you've shown me so far, I think you're misunderstanding what the API docs say.

Comment: Yes, I was misunderstanding which `Group` it was referring to as there is an attribute by the same name. The solution was to add `[VisibleToA(params, Group = "Same"), VisibleToB(params, Group = "Same")]`. In this case, `Group` is a property inside the `Visible` attributes. I'm assuming the processing of the attributes uses that group for the `or` vs `and` condition. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, unfortunately, there is no way to (declaratively) conditionally apply two attributes to your class/method/property, they are either applied, or not, so in your case you have both `VisibleToA` *and* `VisibleToB`. Values provided to attribute constructors must also be compile-time constants, which is probably also part of your problem.

In terms of your design, it sounds to me like you've got some amount of business logic in your attribute classes themselves, which might be causing your problem. It's generally good design practice to restrict the amount of actual logic contained in attributes, and instead have some other mechanism to interpret the metadata that you've applied to your classes/methods/properties.

If you can change your design, I would suggest something like the following:

```
public enum VisibilitySpecifier
{
    A,
    B,
}

public class AndVisibleToAttribute : Attribute
{
    public VisibilitySpecifier[] Visibility { get; set; }

    public AndVisibleToAttribute(params VisibilitySpecifier[] visibility)
    {
        Visibility = visibility;
    }
}

public class OrVisibleToAttribute : Attribute
{
    public VisibilitySpecifier[] Visibility { get; set; }

    public OrVisibleToAttribute(params VisibilitySpecifier[] visibility)
    {
        Visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

Then, simply process the values in the Visibility property according to the logic defined by the particular attribute chosen.